# Logcat analysis Android

Tags: applications, logging

I am analysing the logs of an app and I found this message after the app has been successfully lanuched

```
ActivityTaskManager: The Process packagename Already Exists in BG. So sending its PID: 14389
W/ActivityTaskManager( ): Activity top resumed state loss timeout for ActivityRecord{28ecd14 u0 packageName/full_path_toActivity}
W/ActivityTaskManager( 1566): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord
```

When I am running the same app multiple times (under the same environment, like running the app for the same amount of time, without manual intervention, clearing the logcat before launching of the app), then also ***the number of times, the particular tag is shown on the logcat is  different*** (I am filtering the logs using package name and the pid of the app). I want to know why the frequency of the tags are coming different even though I have not modified the apk.

Is it like there are few tags whose frequency should be same and there are ones for which it may be different?

I want to know the meaning of various tags which are coming from the Android SDK side like ActivityTaskManager, ActivityManager, etc in the logcat, (i.e the tags which are not being written by the developer of the app). Would you like to recommend to read any document so that I will be more comfortables understaing these Tags in the logcat?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The best "document" you can read is the AOSP source code. Google provides the AOSP source code with all braches of all versions. Additionally AOSP source code is mirrored to GitHub and some other places.

Comment: Android also provides a simple interactive user interface for browsing source code on [Android Code Search](https://cs.android.com/)